# how to send FORMDATA() through request.json to php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have two associative arrays that I combined and then appended their keys and values to the formData object I created. However I am trying to send that information to a php file using a new Request.SJON({ method. I don't know if i am doing it correctly but i'm not getting anything on the php file where i am decoding the formData see below. See below:
const employees= {... partTime,... fullTime};

**js file**

```
    for (let[key, value] of Object.entries(employees)){
        formData.append(key, value);
    }


    submitRequest.setOptions({
        data : {
            'formData' : formData
        }
    }).send();
}
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    submitRequest = new Request.JSON({
        method : 'post',
        async : true,
        url : 'warehouse.php',
        data: {
            'action' : 'submit',
            'formData' : ''
        },
        onRequest : function() {
            console.log('on request');
        },
        OnSuccess : function(response){


**php file**

$inputs = json_decode($_POST['formData']);
if ($thisaction == 'submit') {
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tblempoyeeInfo(hiredDate, userID, emplopyeeID, firstDay, lastDay, position, phone)
            VALUES (:var1, :var2, :var3, :var4, :var5, :var6, :var7);");
            $stmt->bindParam(':var1', $decFD->dtdate , PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':var2', userid, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $stmt->bindParam(':var3', $employeeid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':var4', $begintime , PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam(':var5', $endtime, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->bindParam(':var6', $position , PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':var7', $phoneNum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for send data.

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
```